# problem package react-toggle-dark-mode in typescript

Tags: typescript, darkmode

```
import { DarkModeSwitch } from "react-toggle-dark-mode";
const NavBar = () => {
.
.
return {
<div> 
.
<DarkModeSwitch
size={24}
checked={colorTheme === "light" ? false : true}
/>
.
</div>
}
}
```

error :
(alias) const DarkModeSwitch: React.FC
import DarkModeSwitch
Property 'onChange' is missing in type '{ size: number; checked: boolean; }' but required in type 'Props'.ts(2741)
index.d.ts(41, 5): 'onChange' is declared here.

Comment: <DarkModeSwitch  <- error
/>

Comment: DarkModeSwitch needs a `onChange` prop.